# how to change smoke resolution divisions without changing its shape

Tags: smoke-simulation

i'm trying to setup a smoke simulation but faced with the fact that i can't improve the quality of the smoke without changing its shape.
as you can see, the smoke puffs on the 128 are much larger and more expressive, while on the 600 the shape is more diffuse.

[image]

could you please help me out here? what parameter is responsible for this?
here are my settings and scene:

[image]

here is scene file in any case:

[image]

EDIT: i found that there was an option called "high resolution" but it is no longer present in the latest versions of blender. perhaps there is some alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the parameter that response for the quality of the smoke using noise option.
for those who will face the same problem, here are the parameters that you should play with:

*Domain > Physics > Settings > Resolution Divisions* - this parameter is responsible for the voxel size. hence, the smaller the value, the larger the smoke clumps will be, the larger the value, the smaller the smoke clumps will be

*Domain > Physics > Gas > Upres Factor* - that parameter is responsible for the quality of the noise itself, and therefore the smoke. higher values the better the result, but the calculation time is also longer